# About Levin's constructure of universal OWF, why $\log n$ bits TM can work?

Tags: one-way-function

In [Pass's lecture notes](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs6830/2009fa/lecnotes.pdf) 2.13 section, a universal OWF is constructed. But I have some confusion about:

> Let $M_g$ be the smallest machine which computes function $g$. Since $M_g$ is a uniform algorithm it has some constant description size $|M_g|$. Thus, on a random n-bit input $y = <M, x>$, the probability that machine $M = M_g$ (with appropriate padding of 0) is
> $2^{-\log n} = 1/n$.

$g$ in the context is a strong OWF. $|M| = \log n$ in the quote.

I mean, $\log n$ bits just generate $n$ Turing machines, why the specific $g$ must be there?
So the $n$ Turing machines are all the TM?

I know that Turing machine is countable when alphabet set and other settings are fixed. But why in this case $n$ TMs can work?

It confused me for days, can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crucial sentence is

> Since $M_g$ is a uniform algorithm it has some **constant** description size $|M_g|$.

Uniform means that the *same* machine can compute the function $g$ for arbitrary input lengths. This machine then has a *constant* size description that is in particular independent of $n$.

So for a large enough $n$, $\log n \geq |M_g|$.